# How to receive an object on a socketServer in java

Tags: java, sockets

I want to send an object(array) from a client to a server. I use the ObjectInputStream and the ObjectOutputStream. However, this invokes an error, that these methods are not defined in serverSocket class. 
How do I resolve the situation ??`

```
public int[] readResponse() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    int[] x = new int[5];



    ObjectOutputStream cO = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream()); //here is the error
    ObjectInputStream cI = new ObjectInputStream(serverSocket.getInputStream()); // here is the error

    cO.writeObject(x); 

     x = (int[]) cI.readObject();
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
         System.out.println(x[i]);
     }
     return x;
    }
```

Comment: What is the class of the serverSocket object? I don't see it defined locally

Answer (score 1):

A java.net.ServerSocket is not meant to be used for actual input and output; it is a socket for listening on the server to incoming connection requests which are accepted, resulting in a java.net.Socket which is then the one for reading and writing.

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
ObjectInputStream cI = 
     new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

On the client side, a java.net.Socket is created by calling the constructor and connected, via an address, to the client.

```
Socket socket = new Socket( address, port );
ObjectOutputStream cO =
     new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: So should I replace this serverSocket with every Socket object ??

Comment: You use (in the server) one ServerSocket. After each accept you have another Socket for data transfer i/o. "Replace" is not the correct word; you may have to redesign but you haven't posted your logic, only some statements out of context.